# How to create an HTML Input dynamically using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, textbox

I want to create below html inputs dynamically using jQuery inside the form. Is this possible using jQuery?

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Enter Name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameId" name="fullNme" placeholder="Enter full Name">
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to place the above dynamic div and texbox under **div class="box-body"**

```
<form id="myform" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
  <div class="box-body">


  </div>
</form>
```

Can someone help how can I achieve in Jquery/Javascript?

Appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: you want to create all the above elemets?

Comment: @Anoop Joshi - Yes

Comment: `$('YOURCLICK').on('click',function(e){
   $('box-body').append('<input type="text"  class="YOURCLASS" name="YOURNAME[]">')
})`

Comment: @javabegineer see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do,

```
var formgroup = $("<div/>", {
  class: "form-group"
});
formgroup.append($("<label>", {
  class: "col-sm-2 control-label",
  text: "Enter Name"
}));
var colsm = $("<div/>", {
  class: "col-sm-10"
});
var input = $("<input/>", {
  type: "text",
  class: "form-control",
  id: "nameId",
  placeholder: "Enter Full Namee"
});
colsm.append(input);
formgroup.append(colsm);
$(".box-body").append(formgroup);
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/20400/)

You can give any number of attributes like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
<script>
    var html = '<div class="form-group"><label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Enter Name</label><div class="col-sm-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameId" name="fullNme" placeholder="Enter full Name"></div></div>';

    $('.box-body').html(html);
</script>
```

Another way is:

```
<div id="container-bkp" style="display:none">
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Enter Name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameId" name="fullNme" placeholder="Enter full Name">
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
    $('.box-body').html($('#container-bkp').html());
</script>
```